# 'this' in javascript, how to use it in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im constructing dom elements dynamically in this way

```
let constructTrack = (track) =>{
let trackElement = `
        <div class="small-4 columns custom-columns trackCardContent track-card-labels text-right">
            <i data-trackID="${track.trackID}" class="material-icons custom-btn view-track-details-btn">open_in_new</i>
            <i data-trackID="${track.trackID}" class="material-icons custom-btn edit-track-details-btn">mode_edit</i>
            <i data-trackID="${track.trackID}" class="material-icons custom-btn delete-track-btn">delete</i>
        </div>
    `
return trackElement;
}
```

and am trying to assign on click listener in this manner

```
let assignListeners = () =>{
$('.view-track-details-btn').on('click', () =>{
   console.log('view track clicked');
   let id = $(this).data('trackID'); //IS THIS PROPER WAY TO USE 'THIS'
   console.log(id);
});
}
```

As there would be multiple dom elements created , Im assigning "on-click listener" to a 'class' and after that I want to make use of 'this' and access the data dash value , but I am getting it as undefined, please suggest me how to use 'this' or suggest me any other way to handle this issue... (I dont want to add individual on click listener to each dom element created dynamically as it is not a good practice) thanking you in advance.

Comment: Remove `() =>`. It will override context. Use normal function.

Comment: `data()` is not case sensitive, **it must be lowercase**.  See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m9k8899k/   so you need `$(this).data("trackid")`  (and ideally change the html to `<i data-trackid=` )

Comment: @Rajesh It worked ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.view-track-details-btn').on('click')` will add a click listener to all *existing* elements at the time of **execution**.

You should attach the listener on the `DOM` object for all matching elements like so:

`$(document).on('click', '.view-track-details-btn'...` this will always work no matter how or when the elements are generated

and yes, `$(this)` is correct within that context

Comment: let populateTracks = (data) =>{
    let elements = "";
     for(let key in data){
         elements = constructTrack(data[key]) + elements;
     }
    $tracksContainer.html("") ;
     $tracksContainer.prepend(elements);
     assignListeners();

}

"actually  I am assigning the listner in this manner, after adding the elements to the dom only I attaching the listeners.
still when I console.log it I am getting output as 'undefined'

even for this I am getting output as undefined
 $(this).attr("data-trackID");

Answer (score 0):

> get value using attr().
>     Try this

```
$('.view-track-details-btn').on('click', () =>{
   console.log('view track clicked');
   var id = $(this).attr("data-trackID");//change this
   console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: I tried 
$(this).attr("data-trackID");//change this
   console.log(id);
Still I am getting output as undefined

Comment: The issue was with arrow function, I used regular old school function and it worked

Comment: repalce with this  -  var  id =  $(this).attr("data-trackID");  because you call var id  in console  not define.

Answer (score 0):

by removing arrow function here

```
$('.view-track-details-btn').on('click', () =>{
     console.log('view track clicked');
     $(this).attr("data-trackID");//change this
     console.log(id);
});
```

and using regular function

```
$('.view-track-details-btn').on('click', function(){
     console.log('view track clicked');
     $(this).attr("data-trackID");//change this
     console.log(id);
});
```

the issue for resloved

> This happened because arrow functions override the context